# Error:Unexpected reserved word

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, chai, babeljs

I am trying to run simple test case but facing an error "unexpected reserved keyword" and its pointing to `import` keyword from the line `import * as chai from 'chai'`
below is my test code :

```
"use strict"
require('babel-register')({
  presets: [ 'es2015' ]
});
// Import chai.
import * as chai from 'chai'
import * as MathUtils from './sample' 
const should = chai.should;

let SampleTest = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'sample.js'));

describe('Sampletesting', () => {
    describe('function sum', function(){
        it('should return number', function(){
            MathUtils.sum(1).should.equal(1);
        })
    })
});
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha test/*.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "mocha": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

trying to test the below code :

```
function sum(a:number):number{
  return a;
}
module.exports.sum=sum;
```

i dont understand why i am getting the error

Infact i have installed `babel`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that form of importing supported by nodejs?

Comment: no 
that is why i installed babel

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually [transform your source code file with babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation). `babel-register` only affects future calls to `require()`, it does not automagically transform the current file (since the JavaScript parser needs to parse the document before babel has a chance to do anything).